# Error message on my command line the error states remote origin already exist

Tags: git

> Error remote origin already exist

When trying to use `git branch -M main` on my command line I get this error. It's telling me how to fix the problem then by trying `git push -u origin main` but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What other commands have you run?